# SharePoint -how to show List data on a custom web part/ web user control?

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying every option to show List data on a web part and web user control, but I am not finding any code examples on this. What namespace should I import?

I am using WSS 3.0 and I will later upgrade to MOSS 2007. I am aware of the SmartPart project and I can use it in my environment.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first look at the Data View Web Part (DVWP) to see if that will fit your needs. With some XLST/JavaScript you can get very creative with this.

[Data View Web Part Basics](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/05/12/data-view-web-part-the-basics-insert-a-dvwp-on-your-page/)

Otherwise you need to understand two things :-

**[Creating a Basic web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415817.aspx)**

*This is for VS2010/SharePoint 2010 but you will find similar walkthroughs for other versions such as :-*

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/webforms/article.php/c12293/

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/kmcgrath/Creating-a-Web-Part-for-SharePoint-by-Using-a-Designer/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/Generic_Webparts.aspx

**Accessing SharePoint List data**

Then once you've got your basic web part you need to know how to use the object model to open a list and iterate through the items in a list to display the data in whatever funky way you want.

[Accessing list items](http://www.sharepointdevwiki.com/display/public/Accessing+list+items+using+the+object+model)